# How long did it take for the universe to become 1 one light year?

Tags: time, space-expansion, big-bang, density, cosmological-inflation

Given the density, pressure and other cosmological parameters. At this point we're not even thinking of time... But would this have occurred during or post Inflation?

Could this be the Expansion Speed x Age of the Universe x Speed of Light?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/

Comment: Do you mean the universe or the visible universe?

Comment: Both, as I understand it. Inflation at the big bang.

Comment: You understand wrong. See the linked question.

Comment: If the universe is closed then by observations it must have a certain minimum size. The question could be asked for the minimal universe.

Answer (score 2):

> [a light-year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-year) is the distance that light travels in vacuum in one Julian year (365.25 days) Because it includes the word year, the term light-year is sometimes misinterpreted as a unit of time.

So in a [standard graph](http://www.universetoday.com/54756/what-is-the-big-bang-theory/) of the Big Bang model of evolution one year from the Big Bang is a bit after the 3 minutes line, definitely not in the inflation period. One has to assume that light will have traveled for one year to reach that  point, fulfilling the definition, since the model assumes that the velocity of light is always c.

Also one has to keep in mind that one is talking of a three dimensional sphere embedded in a four dimensional space, all points of the universe are a light year's distance from the Big Bang at a bit after 3 minutes on the graph.

[image: historyof univers]